# Extract HTML table from email attachment to Excel and upload to SharePoint

Tags: html, power-automate

I need to extract a table from an HTML file and convert that into Excel format and upload to SharePoint. I've tried extracting the table using a Compose formula like this `slice(outputs('Compose'),indexOf(outputs('Compose'),'<table'),indexOf(outputs('Compose'),'</table'))` but it returned a blank value. Help?

```
<table class="c50">
<tr class="c0">
<td valign="top" class="c1"><p class="c2"><span class="c3"><b>Header Id</b></span></p>
</td>
<td valign="top" class="c4"><p class="c5"><span class="c3"><b>Order Number</b></span></p>
</td>
<td valign="top" class="c6"><p class="c7"><span class="c3"><b>Receipt Date</b></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="c0">
<td valign="top" class="c46"><p class="c2"><span class="c47">29320250</span></p>
</td>
<td valign="top" class="c48"><p class="c5"><span class="c47">696157</span></p>
</td>
<td valign="top" class="c49"><p class="c7"><span class="c47">2023/08/24 00:00:00</span></p>
</td>
</table>
```

Comment: What's your preference ... less operations with a potential cost?  Or, a lot of operations with no cost?

Comment: ... also, will this table ever have more than the header and single data row?

Comment: No cost for sure. There will be more than a single data row.